# Beginner`s Kotlin question. Operating on the array size

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I am following the numerous guides from this website: https://www.w3schools.com/kotlin/kotlin_arrays.php
I am experimenting along the way with my own ideas and such.

For the section detailing how to access elements in an array, I decided that I want to create an output that uses correct grammar in English. I want the list to be displayed as such:

"Volvo, BMW, Ford and Audi."

How can I achieve this? I`m of course an absolute beginner.

Thank you!

```
fun main()  

{   
  val cars = arrayOf("Volvo", "BMW", "Ford", "Mazda") 
  println(cars[3]) // Prints "Mazda"
  if ("Mazda" in cars)
    {
        println("It exists!")
    }
  else
    {
        println("It doesn`t exist!")
    }
  cars[3] = "Audi" 
  println(cars[3]) 
    if ("Mazda" in cars)
    {
        println("It exists!")
    }
  else
    {
        println("It doesn`t exist!")
    }
  println("There are " + cars.size + " elements in this array:") 
  for (w in cars) // The dilemma begins from here
    while (w < cars.size - 1)
        {
            print(w + ", ")
        }
    else 
        {
            print(w + "and " + cars[3] + ".")
        }  
}
```

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for your reply. Ive made that correction and I understand it. Im happy to hear that its at least possible! Ill enjoy figuring out the puzzle now. Thank you

Comment: The other thing I should have mentioned is that you need to iterate your list by indices instead of by its items if you want to check item positions. So use `for ((i, w) in cars.withIndex()) {` so you can check if `i` is less than the array size - 1 rather than checking `w`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Im getting there! Now I have an output of "There are 4 elements in this array:
Volvo, BMW, Ford, Audiand Audi."

Comment: @Tenfour04 My else loop now consists of `println(i in(0..cars.size - 1) + "and " + cars[3] + ".")` but this is giving me an output of `Volvo, BMW, Ford, true` . I`m still vastly unfamiliar with using arrays, but I really would like to know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`while` is a loop with a condition (in the parentheses after it). That's not what you want. And in your comment, you replaced `for` with `println`, which doesn't make sense.

And your `else` branch makes the mistake of using both `w` and `cars[3]` in you final output, two different ways of getting the name of the last car, so it appears twice in your output.

Since you are using both the elements of the array and their indices, you should iterate both at once using `withIndex`, like this.

Here's how you can iterate both the indices and the cars so you can do an `if` condition on the index (position) in the list of each item.

```
for ((i, w) in cars.withIndex()) {
    if (i < cars.size - 1)
    {
        print(w + ", ")
    }
    else 
    {
        print("and " + w + ".")
    }  
}
```

But it's cleaner to use string templates like:

```
for ((i, w) in cars.withIndex()) {
    if (i < cars.size - 1)
    {
        print("$w, ")
    }
    else 
    {
        print("and $w.")
    }  
}
```

When you have short single function calls in each branch of if/else, it sometimes is cleaner looking code to use `when` instead:

```
for ((i, w) in cars.withIndex()) {
    when {
        i < cars.size - 1 -> print("$w, ")
        else -> print("and $w.")
    }  
}
```

Or for a completely different strategy, you could iterate all but the last item by dropping it, and then use just the last item:

```
for (car in cars.dropLast()) {
    println("$car, ")
}
print("and ${cars.last()}")
```

For your comment in your own answer, you can use a `when` statement with three conditions:

```
for ((i, w) in cars.withIndex()) {
    when {
        i < cars.size - 2 -> print("$w, ")
        i == cars.size - 2 -> print("$w ")
        else -> print("and $w.")
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I have replied below!

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. Im going to study what you said a lot now

Answer (score 0):

@Tenfour04

Thank you for your post.
Here is what I settled at before your last post

```
  for ((i, w) in cars.withIndex())
    {
        if (i < cars.size - 1)
            {
                print(w + ", ")
            }
     else 
            {
                for (i in 0..cars.size-4)
                    print("and " + cars[3])
            }  
    }
```

which gave me the output of

```
Volvo, BMW, Ford, and Audi
```

After I`ve corrected it with your solution, **thank you very much.**

The output is still the same:

```
Volvo, BMW, Ford, and Audi
```

Now I am wondering how I can remove the third comma. The one after "Ford", so that the final output would be:

```
Volvo, BMW, Ford and Audi
```

Comment: Not a fan of Oxford commas? :) You could use a `when` statement with three conditions. See my updated answer. Note, you're not supposed to answer your own question with a non-answer. You can comment and/or update your question.

Comment: Sorry, Im new to the site and using a Japanese keyboard at work which is somewhat tricky to have a conversation in in English haha. Ill remember that in future and wont answer my own question again! I appreciate your help.